# Is there anyway to load exisiting data/historical from firestore to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I used exporting collections to bigquery extension to export collections from firestore. But no data is shown. only if we add new data, new data are displayed. Is there any way to load existing data which is in firestore database? new data added after choosing path for collection works but old data are not retrieved.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's about Bigquery UI so no code. Using Bigquery export collection extension, i am able to export the collection but the data present in collection are not exported.  This is more about the extension and not code.

Answer (score 0):

According to Firestore export to Bigquery [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export) lines:

> This extension only sends the content of documents that have been
> changed -- it **does not export your full dataset** of existing documents
> into BigQuery.

Given said this and regards to the Bigquery extension guidelines, you can concern two options with aim having all collection documents being exported to Bigquery:

- Run `fs-bq-import-collection` script, reading all the documents
  within a collection and forcing inserts to Bigquery sink as explained
  [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md);
- Adjust [Firestore managed export](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) service, exporting collection
  documents and storing them to GCS, assuming that these data files can
  be further [loaded](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) to Bigquery as well.

Let me know whether you have any further doubts.

Comment: I tried the fs-bq-import-collection script as well. Only collection were imported and no historical data were imported. From extension we could import subcollection without historical data, but from this script i am unable to import subcollection as well.

Comment: I believe you can follow up this [guide](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/exporting-data-firebase-firestore-bigquery/) to perform the full data Firestore export to Bigquery. Just let us know for the results.